# Undefined refrence to function C++

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I just started coding in C++ and am trying to figure out how the classes and objects work. I have declared a class and object and tried calling functions on the object, but I get a undefined refrence error. Here is my code

Main file where I am creating the object (main.cpp)

```
#include "enemy.h"

int main()
{
    Enemy zombie;
    zombie.health = 10;
    zombie.takeDamage(2);
}
```

Header file for enemy class (enemy.h)

```
#ifndef CITY_H_INCLUDED
#define CITY_H_INCLUDED

class Enemy
{
public:
    int health;

    void takeDamage(int dmg);
};

#endif // CITY_H_INCLUDED
```

cpp file for enemy class (enemy.cpp)

```
#include "enemy.h"

void Enemy::takeDamage(int dmg)
{
    damage -= dmg;
}
```

When I run it I get an error on the line

```
zombie.takeDamage(2);
```

It says: undifined refrence to Enemy::takeDamage(int)
I have checked everywhere and I have no idea whats wrong with my code.

Comment: It looks like you do not include `enemy.cpp` to your build. Please show commands how you build your project.

Comment: I used CodeBlocks but also tried compiling it in cmd with g++ main.cpp -o main

Comment: Then you need to `g++ main.cpp enemy.cpp -o main`. Please check the linked answer for more details.